# Microsoft Edge Developer Tools (DevTools) broken after Windows update

Tags: windows-10, microsoft-edge, developer-tools

Today I had a delayed install of Windows April 2018 update (previous install failed) and now there is an issue with the Microsoft Edge DevTools (debugger). The layout doesn't look right and the size of the windows cannot be adjusted eighter. Here is what my screen looks like:

[Screenshot DevTools](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KiPR0.jpg)

Whereas a normal screen would look like this:

[Screenshot DevTools (normal)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ak2hc.png)

There is no way to resize the window horizontally by dragging the edge. I would like to known if anyone recognizes this issue. At least someone may confirm that this issue does not occur on his/her system with Windows 10 version 17134.228.

Comment: Maybe check under:
`\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\Local Settings\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\AppContainer\Storage\microsoft.microsoftedge_8wekyb3d8bbwe\MicrosoftEdge\F12` at the values. Close Edge, rename the `F12` key, launch Edge then F12.  Maybe Otherwise maybe under `C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Packages\Microsoft.MicrosoftEdge_8wekyb3d8bbwe\AC\#!007\Microsoft\F12`

Comment: I have tried the first suggestion. Windows creates a new F12 key in the registry, but it does not solve the problem. To me it looks very much like something is wrong with the installation, so I won't try further registry editing. Unless someone is really sure what is wrong.